# Updating one sheet by date in another sheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

How can I update information on one sheet by entering a date that refrenced a list of data on a seperate sheet?

For example Sheet1 has a weekly sched. and Sheet2 has a log of events listed by date. I would like to simply enter a date on Sheet1 (i.e. Week of: 9/17/12) and have it update the rest of the sched with the coresponding events from sheet2. 
(the information I'm using is all text)

Thank you in advance!

Comment: This is a basic function of excel but it would depend on how your data is structured. I recommend posting a screenshot - you are likely to get a helpful answer if you do. See my answer below for one possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could use HLOOKUP (assuming your date is organized with headers like in my example):

```
=HLOOKUP($H$1,$A$1:$E$21,ROW(),FALSE)
```

[image: HLOOKUP Example]

Again, like I said in my comment, the answer depends on how your data is organized. But you will proably use some kind of LOOKUP function. Good Luck.